# Python signal event terminates time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

When running the bellow code, why does `time.sleep()` terminate as soon as the signal alarm arrives, instead of continuing after the singal handler has finished with `print signum`?

```
import signal, time


def handler (signum, frame):
    print signum


def main ():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(2)
    time.sleep(10)
    print "End of main"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It is a good thing that signals may terminate `time.sleep()`. Imagine you wrote some loop and accidently had too many zeroes on your sleep time. Would you be happy with Python reacting to SIGINT in a timely manner, or would you prefer it to run for the unwanted 5000 seconds before it can be terminated? ;) And think about the implications for SIGKILL, where the kernel might try to save the whole system from a process running amok (although SIGKILL technically cannot be caught).

Comment: JFYI `time.sleep()` in Python 3.5 or above does what you want. Source: [*time.sleep()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number of real-time seconds specified in seconds has elapsed or until a signal arrives which is not ignored.

You can define a custom sleep function as follows:

```
import datetime
import time
def busy_sleep(seconds):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    seconds_slept = 0
    while seconds_slept < seconds:
        time.sleep(seconds - seconds_slept)
        seconds_slept = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
```

Just call `busy_sleep(10)`  instead of `time.sleep(10)`.

Comment: Is there a way of still using time.sleep() and combining it with a non-terminating signal alarm?